# ocaml parser and lexer

Tags: parsing, ocaml, lexer, parser-generator

Hi I have the 3 files nano.ml which is the type, and a paser and lexer file.  I have no idea how to write the rules for parser, and i try to write the rules but it gives me erro saying that does not accept argument.
when i try to compile it gives me this

```
:File "nanoParse.mly", line 31: $1 refers to terminal `LET', which has no argument
Compiling (to byte code) OCAML module nanoLex.ml
ocamlc -dtypes -c nanoLex.ml -o nanoLex.cmo
File "nanoLex.mll", line 10, characters 32-37:
Error: The constructor LET expects 1 argument(s),
but is here applied to 0 argument(s)
```

and the program suppose to do something like this:

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want `{Let($2, $3, $5)}` instead of `{Let($1, $2, $3)}`. However, this is a lot of code to look through. You might want to start with a tiny example and work up from there.

Comment: but it still saying :Error: The constructor LET expects 1 argument(s),
       but is here applied to 0 argument(s)

Comment: File "nanoLex.mll", line 10, characters 32-37:  which is the lexer, so what i have to change to let it accept argument?

Comment: i did change it to ($2,$3,$5),but change i have make in the lexer now?

Comment: You should change all the other parser rules in a similar way. Also change `In` to `IN`. When I do this, everything compiles. I don't get a complaint from ocamllex.

Comment: yea I did change that,but i got complaint about the lexer

Comment: so there is nothing i have to change in the lexer?